# Angular 5 getting this error Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'

Tags: angular, typescript

Return object looks like this

```
data: { "23":
       { prop: abc, prop_2: def },
        "78":
       { prop: abc, prop_2: def },
       "2098":
       { prop: abc, prop_2: def },
      }
```

Code

```
<div *ngFor="let filterCar of data">
     // blah blah
  </div>
```

Comment: You are trying to iterate over JSON object, and not Array. You should transform your object to an array of objects if you want to use *ngFor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should transform your object into an array of object with Object.values :

```
let tab = Object.values(data);
```

And then you can iterate over it with ngFor

```
<div *ngFor="let filterCar of tab">
 // blah blah
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `*ngFor` on Object, just array, you should transform your object into an array of your object with `Object.entries` :

```
const arrayOfObject = Object.entries(data);
```

And then you can iterate over new variable with `*ngFor`

```
<div *ngFor="let item of arrayOfObject "></div>
```

[MDN Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)